# ZFS on RedHat configuration

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs, zfs

I have to set up a ZFS storage appliance (Oracle ZFS Storage ZS3-2) with NFSv4. The NFS is mounted on a Redhat 6.5 cluster, where the linux users are created (they don`t exist on the appliance). However I can not access the volume since the users do not match. How can I sync the users and control everything from the linux side? I would like to be able to set quotas and shares from the linux machine on the storage.

Is this even possible?

Thank you

Comment: Oracle ZFS Storage solutions are Solaris based (according to their web presentation). So you will eventually figured out how to sync 2 Unixes box ;)

Comment: Do you have any directory services? LDAP? That's the traditional process for this.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The appliance offers NIS and LDAP. Since I have none of them set up what would you suggest would be the easier way to do it?

Comment: NIS or LDAP... or maybe try NFSv3.

Comment: Ok, I will try these. Once I got the user mapping up and running, will I be able to set quotas etc from the linux side right?